# How to guarantee the correct order in async request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a iOS application that use Alamofire to make URL requests. I sometimes find the requests arriving in the wrong order when there is very little time between them. This has to do with the nature of async requests as I understand. Is there any way to guarantee the correct order of the requests? I've been thinking you could wait for each request to finish because you have a completion handler or maybe you could handle this at the server side with a timestamp on each request so the server can discard requests that has a lower timestamp. I don't know what's the best solution though.

My code so far:

```
Alamofire.request(
     defaults.string(forKey: "APIurl")! + path,
     method: httpMethod,
     parameters: parameters,
     encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
     headers: headers).responseJSON
     { response in

     // Check if the request was successful
     var success = false
     if (response.result.isSuccess) {
         let statusCode = response.response!.statusCode
         if (statusCode == 200) {
            success = true
        } else {
            showAlert("COULD_NOT_COMPLETE_TASK_TITLE", message: "TRY_AGAIN_LATER")
        }
    }

}
```

I use sliders to change a value between 0 and 100. So in my case the order of the requests are crucial. Let's say I change a slider from 50 to 60. With async requests it sometimes execute first 60 and then 50. This is an issue as it's sent to my API that way and saves the latest value (in this case 50) in the database even though my desired value was 60.

Comment: you can not guarantee the order of async requests, you have to do your logic handling what to do after the request is back.

Comment: If order is important then either dispatch the requests sequentially or coordinate the responses after all of the requests are completed

Comment: The only way to guarantee the order that they finish is to not make second request until first request finishes (which is a really stupid way to solve the problem). Wei Jay is right, that you should write code that isn't not dependent upon the order that the responses come in. We can't help you solve that problem, though, without more context. But, then again, now that we've pointed out that you need to handle them coming in whatever order that they may, you can probably figure it out, too.

Comment: the issue is that if they arrive in the wrong order the API will interpenetrate it incorrectly. I have a slider you can slide from 0 to 100. Lets say I slide it from 50 to 60 and the request is sent in the reverse order (60 to 50). Then I would have the "wrong" data sent to the API. Is there any way do discard requests that took longer to execute?

Comment: You could assign sequential numbers or apply client timestamps sent in the requests to the server, and let it sort it out. Or if you only care about the latest request, cancel prior request before sending the subsequent request. Or if there's a constant flow of activity, maybe you pursue sockets based connection rather than RESTful API. There are tons of ways of solving this. I'd suggest you give us a real-world, practical problem that you're trying to solve, rather than asking us the question in the abstract.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Is it really critical to get hundreds of requests sent as you move the slider along? Often we'd send it to the server when we let go of the slider or do something to confirm the operation.

Comment: Yes, in my case it is. It has to do with the dimmer on a light bulb so you want to see it change as you slide. As it is now I send a maximim 5 requests per second and one request when releasing the slider

Answer (score 0):

If the thread is serial which in your case it is then the order will always be the same as you input it. So calling a few operations asynchronously on a same serial thread will force the operations to preserve that order.

The problem in your case is that you are not calling these operations, Alamofire is calling them. The order is preserved but it depends on when the responses are received and parsed. That means you may have no control over the order of the async operations being called.

You have 2 ways of serializing responses:

1. You need to wait for each response to be completed before you call the next request. If your responses are standard (all look alike) you only need some manager that will store an array of requests and will not call the new one until the previous one is completed. This might be a bit slow since there is no reason (or at least it seems that way in your case) not to perform the requests at the same time.
2. Serialize the responses so they are called in the same order as input. This means you call the requests whenever and responses will be called whenever. But once the response is received you will check for other responses being complete and only if they are you will trigger a callback on this one. That would again mean having some manager that serializes there responses.

So for the second one you would need something like:

```
SerializedRequestManager.performRequest(request, myCallbackClosure)
```

The manager would then save the request into some array of request wrappers like:

```
let requestWrapper = RequestWrapper(request, myCallbackClosure, isCompleted: false)
self.requestPool.append(requestWrapper)
AF.performRequest(request, myInternalClosure)
```

Then on response (`myInternalClosure`) you need to set the correct wrapper to have response to true and then flush the responses from the start of the array. All the responses finished then must be removed from the array:

```
requestWrapper.responseData = data // Same wrapper that was just added into the array
requestWrapper.responseError = error // Same wrapper that was just added into the array
requestWrapper.isCompleted = true
self.flushResponses()
```

So then `flushResponses`:

```
var newPool = [RequestWrapper]() // This is where all the pending items will stay
var shouldFlushResponse = true // Will be set to false with first request that was not completed
self.requestPool.forEach { wrapper in
    if wrapper.isCompleted && shouldFlushResponse {
       wrapper.callback(wrapper.responseData, wrapper.responseError) // perform response closure
    } else {
       shouldFlushResponse = false
       newPool.append(wrapper)
    }
}
self.requestPool = newPool
```

But you need to be very careful about the multithreading here. All the operation on the array `requestPool` should be done on the same thread but it may be any thread you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the order of requests in crucial in your case then you should go for the NSOperationQueue that is the only way to make sure the order of your requests.

Follow [this](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency/) tutorial to have a border idea